# Hashem, dwell in their midst

Tags: theology, mishkan-tabernacle

Shemot 25
8 And they shall make Me a sanctuary and I will dwell in their midst

Vaikra 15:31 and Bemidbar 19:13. It is being implied there that the body is the temple of Hashem.

31 Thus shall ye separate the children of Israel from their uncleanness; that they die not in their uncleanness, when they defile My tabernacle that is in the midst of them.

13 Whosoever toucheth the dead, even the body of any man that is dead, and purifieth not himself--he hath defiled the tabernacle of the LORD--that soul shall be cut off from Israel; because the water of sprinkling was not dashed against him, he shall be unclean; his uncleanness is yet upon him.

If a human is a temple for Hashem, why can´t The spirit of Hashem dwell in a human?And if so, doesn´t it make him as Hashem himself? (It is still just one Hashem, I would guess he coud be at many places at the same time,still one Hashem?) (A man changes many forms in his/her life, it is still the same man?)

Can Hashem live/dwell inside a human? And if not,why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means you can live in the world of God during your tenure in this world.

Your experience of this world will be processed from God's perspective.

Your spirit will not be able to be crushed by any vicissitude of life you will ever experience.